# How to set time to AM/PM for Org clocking?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

Currently, clocking time format is this:

```
    CLOCK: [2021-01-12 Tue 22:45]--[2021-01-12 Tue 23:23] =>  0:38
    CLOCK: [2021-01-12 Tue 16:29]--[2021-01-12 Tue 17:08] =>  0:39
```

Can I change this instead to the AM/PM 12-hour format that I have grown up with?

I looked for the answer online, and I found this good question/answer as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720526/set-clock-table-duration-format-for-emacs-org-mode

I am using org-version 9.3 and emacs-version 27.1. Apparently for org versions 9.1 and above:

```lisp
(setq org-duration-format (quote h:mm))
```

the above variable, `org-duration-format` is to be used. However, I cannot find documentation on how to change this to 12 hour AM/PM format.

The equivalent in elisp string formatting would be `"%I:%M %p"`. However, `org-duration-format` does not accept string values. The online documentation for formatting time in elisp [can be found here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html).

Comment: `org-duration-format` is for *durations*, not for times, so the duration format has nothing to do with an AM/PM specification.

Answer (score 1):

Org mode uses [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) timestamps, so you cannot use the 12-hour AM/PM format as a storage format: Org mode files will always use the 24-hour format.

However, you can change the *appearance* of a timestamp in an emacs buffer by using the variables `org-display-custom-times` and `org-time-stamp-custom-formats`. That is described in the [Custom time format](https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html#Custom-time-format) section of the manual. You lose some functionality by doing this, so it is important to read that section and understand the trade-offs.

If you do decide to go ahead with it, you need to add something like this to your init file:

```el
(setq org-display-custom-times t)
(setq org-time-stamp-custom-formats '("<%m/%d/%y %a>" . "<%m/%d/%y %a %I:%M %p>"))
```

or use the Customize interface to set them. Reading the doc strings of these variables (e.g. `C-h v org-display-custom-times RET`) is *always* a good idea.

If you only want it for some files, then don't set `org-display-custom-times` globally; just set `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` and then use

```
#+STARTUP: customtime
...
```

at the top of your Org mode file.